# Vue search filter on multiple fields and values

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

My web app has a search box. Currently the code searches a bunch of fields, but it only returns results from one field.  How do I make it so that I can search in multiple fields separated by a comma or semicolon?

**CODE EXAMPLE**:

```
return this.builds.sort(compare).filter((build) => {
            return build.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) || build.item1.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
            build.item2.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) || build.item3.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
            build.item4.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
        }
```

For example: one build has a title of *"BEST EVER"* and another build has an item2 of *"THE RED ONE"*.  I would like to be able to search *"BEST, RED"* and have them both show up.

I have no idea how to accomplish this - can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks